# Same Info Split Between Two Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to pull data from a large table and then join it to another table to get a list of addresses. Here's my issue:  in my first table there are two columns, ADDRKEY and PRCLKEY, which both contain the same information. However, for some reason ~80% of the entries have this "address identifier number" in the ADDRKEY field with the PRCLKEY equal to 1 while the other 20% have the "address identifier number" in the PRCLKEY field and the ADDRKEY field entered as 1.

I need a way to use only the real identifier (non 1) from either column in Table1 and join to Table2 on T2.ParcelID = T1.(ADDRKEY or PRCLKEY if > 1)

Comment: please look here to  improve question :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Table2 on T2.ParcelID = Case When T1.ADDRKEY > 1 Then T1.ADDRKEY Else PRCLKEY End
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NULLIF() with COALESCE():

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(ADDRKEY,'1'),NULLIF(PRCLKEY,'1')) AS AddressIndentifier
```